# Suporting SE Earth Science

Tags: discussion

Is anybody else supporting this?

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/earth-science

Comment: This thread seems relevant: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/3333/merge-the-various-geoscience-proposals.  It's a fascinating field.  I hope the proposal succeeds, even though it has taken two years to get going.

Comment: It is amazing at times how the internet can fail to come up with 200 people ;)

Comment: To "sell" SE Earth Science to people here who might be interested in committing to it, you may want to revise your Question with more details about the proposal and what you see as the reasons why some GIS SE people might like to span both sites.

Comment: Well a lot of people here are mapping natural (as opposed to cultural) features of Earth. So I thought they would also appreciate a site concerned with those features and proccesses.

Comment: An expanded version of this Q is now at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3608/gis-is-for-geographic-information-system-what-about-information-systems-for-oth?cb=1